# VB.NET using SendKeys.Send

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

How can use Sendkey to send **right** Control + shift in vb.net ??

I tried:

```
SendKeys.Send("^(shift)")
```

but it gave me a space.

Comment: Isn't CTRL and SHIFT `^+`?  Where did `(shift)` come from?

Comment: Besides my above comment, if you specifically need to send `RCTRL` then you'll probably have to use Win32's `SendMessage` (in `user32.dll`) with the `WM_KEYDOWN` message

Comment: I want to press the right ctrl+shift to change the cursor direction to right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example of how to press CapsLock. I think you'll be able to figure it out for shift+ctrl:

```
   Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal bVk As Byte, _
        ByVal bScan As Byte, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Integer, _
        ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer _
    )
    Private Const VK_CAPITAL As Integer = &H14
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY As Integer = &H1
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

    Private Sub TestKey()

        ' Toggle CapsLock

        ' Simulate the Key Press
        keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)

        ' Simulate the Key Release
        keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the documentation on the SendKeys method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.keyboard.sendkeys

With regards to the `SHIFT` key:

> To combine a key with SHIFT, precede the key code with + (plus sign).

With regards to the `CTRL` key:

> To combine a key with CTRL, precede the key code with ^ (caret).

Now, SendKeys does not support sending specifically the right/left `SHIFT` or `CTRL`. Instead, you will need to use the `SendMessage` API and send the `Keys.RControlKey` enum value. Here is a C# example (can easily be converted to VB.NET):

```c#
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
using System.Diagnostics;  
 
private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;  
 
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]  
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);  

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Keys key = Keys.RShiftKey;//Right shift key  
    SendMessage(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)key, 1);  
}  
 
protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)  
{  
    if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)  
        MessageBox.Show(m.WParam.ToString());  
 
    base.DefWndProc(ref m);  
}
```

Original link from MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd6406e8-b6bf-4166-82a0-6d533def38a5/how-to-send-leftright-shift-key?forum=csharpgeneral#5734fe34-407d-4edc-ae41-9b1eaa12bb23-isAnswer